# creating a 2D circular mesh in Matlab

Tags: matlab, geometry, mesh, polar-coordinates

I have some data on a horizontal line (x,y,data) (2991*3) with y=0.
Instead of plotting the line in a Cartesian coordinate system, I would like to transform that line into a quarter circle and plot the data in a range of color.

I'm able to create a mesh

```
rho = x
theta = (0:0.5:90)*pi/180
[th, r] = meshgrid(theta,rho);
```

The problem I'm having is to plot the circle in 2D and link the data to the mesh.
Any tips would be very welcome!

[image]

Comment: Select the points of the original x,y grid that are such x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, r=radius of the mesh?

Comment: `[x,y] = meshgrid([-1:0.01:1],[-1:0.01:1])`, and then `figure, plot(x(x.^2+y.^2 <=0.25),y(x.^2+y.^2 <=0.25),'rx')`, `axis square` should show a nice disk grid in original cartesian coordinates.

Comment: I like the figure. The text alone is too ambiguous, but this way I get what you want.

Comment: Thank you. I guess if i would know how to explain it I would be able to do it ;) ! The data along the line is a bit more complicated than that, but the overall idea is the figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your call to `meshgrid` is exactly what you want. You just have to generate the data matrix that corresponds to the entries of `th` and `r`.
Your data depends on the values of `r`, and as this is a matrix of increasing values in the rows,

```
r = [rho(1), rho(1), ..., rho(1);
     rho(2), rho(2), ..., rho(2);
     rho(3), rho(3), ..., rho(3);
     ...                        ];
```

you will need to transform your colors `data`, so they correspond to this matrix.
This can be done via `repmat(data(:), 1, size(r,2))`, which generates a matrix, so that the `i`th  row only contains the value `data(i)`:

```
[data(1), data(1), ..., data(1);
 data(2), data(2), ..., data(2);
 data(3), data(3), ..., data(3);
 ...                           ];
```

This way the values correspond to the radius given by the rows of `r`.

### Final result:

Your final script will look like this:

```
%% Example data
x = (2:0.1:8);
data = sin(x);

%% Shift the values towards the center, so you get a circle instead of an annulus.
rho = x-min(x);

%% Your meshgrid generation code.
theta = (0:0.5:90)*pi/180;
[th, r] = meshgrid(theta, rho);

%% Plotting the values
surf(min(x)+r.*cos(th), ...
     min(x)+r.*sin(th), ...
     repmat(data(:), 1, size(th,2)), ...
     'linestyle', 'none'); 
view(2);
axis equal tight;
colorbar;
```

and the output will look like this:[image: Output from function]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which is really intesting as well, however it is not exactly what I had in mind. I have edited my question (i added a figure to show exactly my idea).

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly the 'repmat' option I was looking for. I'll keep that in mind!